# Need to run / test 1500 concurrent Jitsi meet 1 to 1 conference video calls

Tags: webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I require to run 1.5K concurrent 1 to 1 conference video calls. I need help with planning to test and analyze what server requirements would be needed.

The application would need to support 1.5K concurrent 720P video calls. Each call would have only two participants. What would be the best approach to test this application. How would we test the video output if we do automation using selenium. The App would be using Jitsi default libraries for the video conference.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am interested.